# What's your ideal C# project built upon?

Tags: c#

I'm starting a new personal project on the side, so this is the first time I'll be able to start from the ground up on a larger project since ASP.NET 2.0 was first released. I'd like this to also be a good learning experience for me, so right now I'm planning on building this upon ASP.NET MVC, Castle ActiveRecord, and Ninject. I'm most comfortable with MbUnit for unit testing and CruiseControl for CI so right now they are the front runners.

But what would be your first additions once you click "New Solution"? Open Source, commercial, whatever. I have an open mind if they look like they can make it do what it do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Web Framework: MVC**](http://www.asp.net/mvc/)

Just a better way to make web applications

[**OR/M: NHibernate**](http://www.hibernate.org/343.html)

Nothing really beats it in performance or features

[**Javascript: JQuery**](http://jquery.com/)

Been using it before it got all cool. JQuery to me seems less like a framework, and more like a natural extension to the javascript language

[**IoC: Castle Windsor**](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html)

Most mature of the .net IoC containers

[**CI: TeamCity**](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)

Once you try it, you will never want to go back

[**Testing: NUnit**](http://www.nunit.org/index.php)

They are all pretty head to head in features, I prefer the tooling (resharper) and syntax (been using it forever now)

[**Mocking: Rhino Mocks**](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx)

Again, I like to go for maturity, especially in open source projects

In Hanselman [ALT.net Geek Code](http://www.hanselman.com/altnetgeekcode/), that translates to

IOC(CW):MOC(RM):TDD(NU):SCC(Svn):ORM(NH):XPP(++):DDD(T+):JSL(Jq):CIS(TC):GoF(++)

Comment: SO seems to be stripping out all the CSS from the hanselman geek code thing. Thought it was a bit more lenient then that

Comment: I was thinking about giving TeamCity a shot. I've been quite happy with the JetBrain tools. That should have been a no brainer. I'll have to play more with Windsor. I'm kinda new to the whole IoC, but Ninject seemed to be pretty easy for me to get up and running with so that's why I choose it

Comment: The thing is, all IoC containers offer more or less the same performance and features. It is mostly a matter of what you are comfortable with. As for TC, I really can't say enough good things about it. Give it a shot

Comment: I haven't found anything to beat NHibernate either.

Answer (score 3):

Built on nothing.  Personally, I'm not a big fan of using frameworks and pre-built components for every single aspect of my project.  I like to be in control of all the code, and write all the code myself.  You could call it an extreme case of not invented here syndrome.  Or you could say, if it's a core business function, do it yourself.

Comment: Ha, well I work on a project like that here at work. This is just little ol' me trying to branch out on some new technologies. I hate using stuff just to be using it, but I figure if I don't give some of this stuff a shot I might be missing out on a nice tool for future work.

Comment: There is a vast difference between "built on nothing" and not using frameworks "for every single aspect of my project".

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Microsoft Unity for IoC, for NHibernate make sure you look into Fluent NHibernate and say good bye to the xml garbage!

I wrote my own version of the Web Client Software Factory that leverages Unity instead of ObjectBuilder(1) that's included as I ran into numerous issues with it, at some point it will be blogged about in a series of posts but the source code is already on my site which you can view in my profile.

If your project is for an enterprise in all honesty I would recommend against using the MVC Framework. It's such a large derivation from web forms that you will find many developers that don't live and breathe coding will not be able to use it correctly and you will constantly be fighting to keep the MVC usage correct as most developers will treat it the same way as web forms.